# more efficient awk parser for different combinations of data

Tags: awk

I have an awk parser, that works great if the data is NC_0000 (four digits), but if it is not that then the data is parsed. I'm not sure the most efficient way to obtain the desired output.  Thank you :).

Code:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 && match($0, /NC_0000([0-9]*)\..*g\.([0-9]+)(.)>(.)/, a){ print a[1], a[2], a[2], a[3], a[4] }' OFS='\t' ${id}.txt > ${id}_parse.txt
```

For example:

```
NC_000013.10:g.20763466G>A
NC_00001.10:g.20763477C>G
```

would be parsed into the desired output of

```
13  20763466    20763466    G   A 
1   20763477    20763477    C   G
```

but this

```
NC_000004.11:g.41749507G>T
```

would not work.  The desired output format is listed below and is always that way.  Thank you :).

parse rules:

1. 4 zeros after the NC_ (not always the case) and the digits before the .
2. digits after the g. repeated twice separated by a tab
3. letter before the >
4. letter after the >

added using

```
awk -F"[_.>]" '{a=length($4);b=substr($4,1,a-1);print $2+0,b,b,substr($4,a),$5}' OFS="\t" Target.txt
0
4004    244     244     G       A               NC
3924    288     288     C       A               NC
3924    385     385     G       A               NC
```

Thank you:)

Comment: Try to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You've asked a few questions so far and haven't accepted any, neither dear to format properly.

Comment: Since you aren't accepting any answers we have to assume that none of the answers you are receiving here are useful to you and so we may as well close this one so no-one wastes more time on it.

Comment: I reformated the question to be like the post, I hope its better.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
cat file
NC_000013.10:g.20763466G>A
NC_00001.10:g.20763477C>G
NC_000004.11:g.41749507G>T
```

```
awk -F"[_.>]" '{print $2+0,substr($4,1,8),substr($4,1,8),substr($4,9,1),$5}' OFS="\t" file
13      20763466        20763466        G       A
1       20763477        20763477        C       G
4       41749507        41749507        G       T
```

---

If number of digits after `g.` may change, use this:

```
awk -F"[_.>]" '{a=length($4);b=substr($4,1,a-1);print $2+0,b,b,substr($4,a),$5}' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: The results I get are different using the second awk, I posted them in the original thread.  Thank you :).

Comment: @user3665765 With the data in your post I get this output. (see data in my post). Add more input data to your post and format the data correctly.